# How to stop ports.conf getting modified by certbot

Tags: apache2, certbot

How can I get certbot to stop modifying /etc/apache2/ports.conf, but still autorenew?

I have a ports.conf that looks like this

```
 NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080
 Listen 127.0.0.1:8080

 <IfModule ssl_module>
   Listen 443
 </IfModule>

 <IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
   Listen 443
 </IfModule>
```

I am using nginx to redirect http traffic to apache, as I have a flask server running at http://mydomain/api/ recieving requests.

The  problem I am having is that since I set up certbot with apache, it keeps adding this line to my *ports.conf* file which then crashes apache :(

```
Listen 80
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the Cerbot **nginx** plugin (**python-certbot-nginx** package on Debianoids) and modify the renewal parameters in `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal/<your_domain>.conf`:

```
[renewalparams]
authenticator = nginx
server = https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
installer = nginx
account = <your_account_id>
```

Let's Encrypt needs port `80` to authenticate your domain and that port is occupied by **nginx**.

Comment: Yep so I stopped `certbot`, installed `python-certbot-nginx` package and modified by renew conf files. I can confirm that this works exactly like one would hope.